# How a pass a value with $$ in it to a shell script

Tags: shell, parameters

e.g `ksh myshell.sh parm1, $$param2.`

I want to assign the second parameter to a variable inside my shell script

e.g. `var1=$2`

and then use it as `$var1`,

i.e. **var1** should have value `$$param2` when I use it as `$var1` inside my shell script.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds about right. You just need to make sure you quote the call to `my shell.sh` correctly, so that the shell doesn't expand the `$$` before your script is even called.

```
ksh myshell.sh parm1 '$$param2'
```

or

```
ksh myshell.sh parm1 $\$param2
```

Note that you don't need to escape both dollar signs, although you can if you like. It is *not* sufficient to escape only the first one, since `$param2` would still be expanded.